# Template Inheritance Does Not Work - Django Tutorial

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-templates, django-inheritance

I am following [Corey Schafer' Django tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDwdMDQ8oX4&list=TLPQMTgxMDIwMjHfZT4-p81GEw&index=2). I have reached where I have to create a base.html template inheritance. After adjusting everything according to my project and running the server, my webpage presents itself as a source code in html format. [click to see the page after server run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgb8v.png).

My views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    text = "welcome to the website - python"

    posts = [
        {
            'title': 'The Fault in Our Stars', 'price': '3.0 BD', 'post_date': '24-10-2021'
    },
        {
            'title': 'The Black Swan', 'price': '3.5 BD', 'post_date': '23-10-2021'

    },
        {
            'title': 'Watchmen', 'price': '5.0 BD', 'post_date': '22-10-2021'

        }

    ]

    context = {
        'text': text, 'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context, {'title': 'Bookish Bahrain - Home'})
```

My base.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% if title %}
        <title> {{ title }} </title>
    {% else %}
        <title> Bookish Bahrain </title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

My index.html code:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <p> {{post.title}} </p>
        <p> {{post.price}} </p>
        <p> {{post.post_date}} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

My Django version is 3.9.7.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're expecting the title to be added to the context but it's not? You can't pass multiple context dictionaries, you need to combine them into one

Comment: @IainShelvington I placed the title in the context dictionary and it worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just should do this:

```
    context = {
        'text': text, 'posts': posts,
        'title': 'Bookish Bahrain - Home'
    }
    return render(request,'blog/index.html', context )
```

Checkout this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/